# LEFT JOIN on multiple tables ERROR! (Table or view does not exist)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, ora-00942

I have the following SQL Syntax:

```
  SELECT firmenstamm.firmen_id,   
     firmenstamm.firmenname_1,   
     kreditorenstamm.kreditorenname_1,   
     debitor.debitoren_id,   
     debitor.deb_id_vom_kreditor,   
     debitorenstamm.debitorenname_1,   
     zahlung.zahlung_nr,   
     zahlung.zahlung_betrag,   
     zahlung.zahlung_betrag_offen,   
     zahlung.zahlung_datum,   
     kreditorenstamm.kreditoren_id,   
     bankbewegung.name_ag,   
     bankbewegung.verwendungzweck  
FROM debitor,   
     debitorenstamm,   
     firmenstamm,   
     kreditorenstamm,   
     zahlung 
     LEFT JOIN z_bankbewegung ON zahlung.zahlungs_id =   z_bankbewegung.zahlungs_id,
     LEFT JOIN bankbewegung ON z_bankbewegung.babe_id = bankbewegung.babe_id

 WHERE ( firmenstamm.firmen_id = kreditorenstamm.firmen_id ) and  
         ( kreditorenstamm.kreditoren_id = debitor.kreditoren_id ) and  
         ( debitor.debitoren_id = debitorenstamm.debitoren_id ) and  
         ( debitor.kreditoren_id = zahlung.kreditoren_id ) and  
         ( debitor.deb_id_vom_kreditor = zahlung.deb_id_vom_kreditor ) and  
         ( ( zahlung.zahlung_betrag_offen > 0 ) )
```

My Problem now is the following:
As you can see I made a multiple left join on the same table. I always get the error message "Table or view does not exist" (ORA-00942).

```
zahlung 
LEFT JOIN z_bankbewegung ON zahlung.zahlungs_id =   z_bankbewegung.zahlungs_id,
LEFT JOIN bankbewegung ON z_bankbewegung.babe_id = bankbewegung.babe_id
```

I can't see my mistake. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do **not** mix implicit joins and explicit `JOIN` operators. Write everything with an explicit `JOIN` operator

Comment: okay I'm not that pro in SQL :D Can you give me an example what you mean with explicit and implicit ?

Comment: try to keep it simple via alias, use visual editor if it is possible. which software of database you are using.

Comment: As suggested, don't mix the implicit and explicit join styles. However, the actual cause of your issue is the comma you have at the end of your first explicit join condition: `LEFT JOIN z_bankbewegung ON zahlung.zahlungs_id = z_bankbewegung.zahlungs_id,`. I mention this for your information only!

Comment: Eintracht Frankfurt ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are mixing the old, ancient and fragile implicit joins (listing all tables separated by a comma in the FROM clause, then put the join conditions in to the WHERE clause) and the "modern"<sup>1)</sup> explicit JOIN operator. Don't do that. Use explicit JOINs for everything:

```
SELECT ...
FROM debitor
  JOIN debitorenstamm ON debitor.debitoren_id = debitorenstamm.debitoren_id
  JOIN kreditorenstamm ON kreditorenstamm.kreditoren_id = debitor.kreditoren_id
  JOIN firmenstamm ON firmenstamm.firmen_id = kreditorenstamm.firmen_id
  JOIN zahlung
    ON debitor.kreditoren_id = zahlung.kreditoren_id
   AND debitor.deb_id_vom_kreditor = zahlung.deb_id_vom_kreditor
  LEFT JOIN z_bankbewegung ON zahlung.zahlungs_id = z_bankbewegung.zahlungs_id
  LEFT JOIN bankbewegung ON z_bankbewegung.babe_id = bankbewegung.babe_id
WHERE zahlung.zahlung_betrag_offen > 0
```

---

1) "modern" is relative: explicit JOINs have been introduced in the SQL standard in 1992 more than 25 years ago. So that's hardly "modern" in the sense of "brand new".

Comment: Awesome Explanation! Thank you so much. I just got 1 more question. Is there a reason why you wrote "Debitor" as the first table or was is just randomly and is there no Need to care about the order?

Comment: @fnr: it was the first table in your statement. For an inner join the order doesn't matter though.

Comment: The optimiser will decide the join order, but all the same it is worth writing the joins in some logical order for the sake of maintainability. I would also write all of the predicates forwards e.g. `from a join b on b.something = a.something` rather than reversing everything as in your original version.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Can you explain: positive vs. negative ("original version") example?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty not sure what you mean by "positive vs. negative". I don't think I mentioned anything positive or negative.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty If you want rows for employee 246, do you write `where 246 = empno` or `where empno = 246`? If you then want to look up the department name, wouldn't `from emp e join dept d` express what you trying to do more clearly than `from dept d join emp e` (which reads like you are querying `dept` and then looking up the employee details)? This is what I'm getting at with "logical order" and "forwards".